# htaccess subdomain id category

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, categories

plz i want change categories  to subdomains with htaccess:
Example
this is my url

http://my-url.com/index.php?id_cat=29&l=category-name-here

and i want to rewrite it to :

http://category-name-here.my-url.com

```
   and this is what i try but i cant find what i want 

        Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.your-domain-name.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).your-domain-name.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /some_file.php/$1?subdomain=%2 [L,QSA]


thank you
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? What's to stop someone from submitting `your-domain-name.com?category=really nasty bad words here` and Google indexing `really.nasty.bad.words.your-domain-name.com`?

Comment: its all about google indexing 
subdomain its more power thene folder name ( SEO )